# Can I take "ownership" of another logon?

Tags: support, accounts

I had a Linux question that led me to reading things on Unix/Linux Exchange. I could not log on, tried asking for Password forgot, said my email was not in use.

So I registered using my google account.
I asked one question.

Now, went back to my windows pc and found I DID have an account but was under stackoverflow didn't know they didn't share until you explicitly linked.

Not a big deal, it is only one question but I rather dump that account so can keep em all under one umbrella.

I had 2 questiosn, so now that linked to my original Stackoverflow, I tried to ask one on Linux/Unix and got the "can only post one per 40 mins"

Is it looking at IP? lol because I just tried to ask first time under this name, if I look at info on my profile it says I have no questions under Linux/Unix section. (I do, but logged on via google which I'd like to combine or delete)

Comment: Thank you - I read it and will comply. Question: I would prefer to keep the "newer" login style - gmail, since I am likely to change carriers in future. But the "verizon" one (this one) is the older account. If I login with new verizon account and ask to merge there- will I "lose" the "since 1year+" time registered? If so, will login as me verizon and absorbe the gmail ;)  Of course if after fact, I can just change logon method to gmail either way - moot point! :)?